# Accordion with different form panels in SenchaTouch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have started to build an app in `SenchaTouch 2.3`. I need to implement a large form an my question is: Can I build an accordion to "group" the form in different parts? This could be the expanded panels:

```
    > Personal Data
    Salutation: Select or Radio
    Firstname: Textfield
    Lastname: Textfield

    > Address
    Street: Textfield
    Zip: Textfield
    Country: Select
    ...

    > Other Data
    ...
```

Perhaps someone can provide a little example. Thank you very much!

Comment: This may help you get started:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767914/sencha-touch-2-0-how-to-split-a-form-across-tab-panels

Answer (score 0):

For the accordion part, your best bet may be to use a library and wrap the collapsible component in a formpanel, grouped using fieldsets. This code may be helpful too. http://kubahulewicz.net/2012/07/18/sencha-touch-2-searchable-grouped-list-with-expandcollapse-functionality/

Comment: This looks really good. I'll try it out and will mark this as the correct answer if it works ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a sweet solution: https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.layout.Accordion

It works like expected and can be modified for my needs.